# login with facebook issue

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

I'm facing a very weird issue, I have an existing app code.

when I tries to login with facebook, browser open and it shows a button "Login with the facebook app", click on that button open's the app and when we gave access it goes back to previous facebook popup insted of going to our app.

I have did searching but dint not found some one facing related issue.

[image: facebook login browser with button]

please help me out if anyone faced same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have set URL Types for your facebook Login.

You can set by select your project Target -> Info -> UrlType

Set your Facebook App id as given below in screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a method in `AppDelegate`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled =  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
    if (![RNBranch.branch application:application openURL:url options:options]) {
           // do other deep link routing for the Facebook SDK, Pinterest SDK, etc
       }

    return handled;
}
```

Also, You need to add your FB Id in URL Type. That you will get in https://developers.facebook.com/

[image: Side Menu]

[image: Configure Your info.plist]

**Note:** Make sure If you any other URL Types as well, you need to combine both.